# Positive integer data type(without 0)

Tags: mysql

I need an integer number that bigger than 0 (1-65535)

Is there any mysql type or attribute like unsigned, but without 0 values?

Comment: No. All numeric data types will include zero.

Comment: Create it as int and then add a trigger that will check whether you inserted 0 or not. If yes, raise an error.

Comment: is there any reason to exclude 0?

Comment: Yes, price shouldn't be 0. I just don't want to add extra checking in all queries "`price`>0". Trigger will help, I know, but thought that there must be some built-in way to do it. Turned out that there was no, thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not. There are 5 different types of integers (6 if you include enum). The closest you can get is `SMALLINT`(0-65535).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

```
TINYINT   0-255
SMALLINT  0-65525
MEDIUMINT 0-16777215
INT       0-4294967295
BIGINT    0-18446744073709551615
```

These are the unsigned values of the integers types.

As mentioned in the comments, you create a small int and add a trigger that will check to see if you inserted a 0.